# using Exec to get the content of a variable

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a program using flask and python3. (See [Repl](https://repl.it/@VelocityDev/Triggletmk2#templates/form.html))
I want to get a variable based on the number of a for loop. I've tried multiple things, but I keep getting this error when I navigate to /new/t

```
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/runner/Triggletmk2/templates/form.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "base.html" %}
File "/home/runner/Triggletmk2/templates/base.html", line 11, in top-level template code
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
  File "/home/runner/Triggletmk2/templates/form.html", line 9, in block "content"
    <nobr><p>{{ exec(this, ldict) }}</p>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'form' is not defined
172.18.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2020 15:27:45]
```

Here is the code for the FOR Loop

```
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {% for x in range(1,formLength) %}
        {% set this = "form."+p.number_to_words(x).replace(" ","") %}
        <nobr><p>{{ exec(this) }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
```